# Does Jquery/Javascript require an elem to be in the DOM to use .css()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

```
if(typeof this.description === 'undefined') {alert('No Description Set!'); return false;}

var tempDiv = document.createElement('div'); //create a div outside of the DOM
tempDiv.className = 'descriptionColumn formBox contentRow'; //make sure and use the 
                    //same/equivlent class(s) to ensure accuracy

tempDiv.innerHTML = this.description; //insert the text

document.body.appendChild(tempDiv); //render div

lineHeight = parseInt($(tempDiv).css('line-height')); //get the line-height (make sure this is specified in CSS!)
                                                      //also we use Jquery here to handle any vender inconsistencies,
divHeight = tempDiv.clientHeight;  //get the div height

tempDiv.parentNode.removeChild(tempDiv); //clean up, delete div
delete tempDiv;

return divHeight/lineHeight;  //divide the height by the line-height and return
```

This code works, I am trying to calculate the number of lines in a div.  That said I wasn't able to get the line-height until after I added this element to the DOM.

Origionally I planned on not adding it at all because I only use it to calcuate the number of lines in the DIV.

It makes sense  that it wouldn't have a height until I added it, I am just wondering if I did the right thing, or if there is a way to get the line-height without adding it to the DOM in the first place.

Comment: Yes, the answer is yes

Comment: can always place the div with position offscreen to do your tests.

Comment: The css is rendered by the browser only when the element is inserted into the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rendering/Layout decision by browser is taken by browser 2 conditions:

1)new element is inserted

2)some element's style has been changed

3)sometimes when window is resized

so until the element is in DOM Tree browser will not give Layout related style to it.

consider following code:

```
var div = document.createElement(div);
var style = window.getComputedStyle(div);
console.log( style.color );//prints "" (empty string)
```

why??
because window.getComputedStyle() returns the CSS style which are actully present in DOM(browser).
now,

```
document.body.appendChild(div);
var style = window.getComputedStyle(div);
console.log( style.color );//prints rgb(somevalue)
```

why??
because rendering engine has decided the CSS properties.

//One gotcha

```
var div2 = document.createElement("div");
div2.style.color = "red";
console.log( $(div2).css("color") ); //prints red because jQuery gives preference to div2.style.color over window.getComputedStyle(div2);
but console.log ( window.getComputedStyle(div2).color );//prints ""   .... this proves that browser has not yet decided the properties of div2
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. But ... if you have jQuery on your page, why don't you use it?

```
var $div = $('<div/>', {
    class: 'descriptionColumn formBox contentRow',
    text: 'Description',
    css: {
        position: 'absolute',
        left: '-99999px'
    }
}).prependTo('body'); // element wouldn't be visible for user on this step
//your calculations
$div.remove();
```